# Java Regex-matches anything except three specific string

Tags: java, regex

Given such `Java` `Regex` codes:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^(bob)(alice)(kitty)]");
String s = "a";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

boolean bl = matcher.find();
System.out.println(bl);
```

The output is `false`. Why? The regex `[^(bob)(alice)(kitty)]` matches any things except `bob`, `alice` or `kitty`. Then the result should be true, right?

Comment: Why do you think that's all it matches?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because your regex is not doing what you think it should be doing.

Use this regex with **Negative lookahead**:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?!bob|alice|kitty).*$");
```

Your regex: `[^(bob)(alice)(kitty)]` is using a **character class** and inside a character class there are no groups.

- `(?!bob|alice|kitty)` is negative lookahead that means fail the match if any of these 3 words appear at start of input.
- Important to use anchors `^` and `$` to make sure we're not matching from middle of the string.
- If you want to avoid matching these 3 words **anywhere in input** then use this regex:

  ```
  ^(?!.*?(?:bob|alice|kitty)).*$
  ```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW6oL2/2)

Comment: Don't you need to add `$` within the lookahead? Otherwise, `bobfoobar` won't match while it should.

Comment: Seems works. Can you make more explanation about the `$` here? I will accept this answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: Added details to answer.